# Outlook addin - js or api generate email file

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an outlook addin that I've built using Yeoman.  The addin communicates with a server API on my server to combine data from an email with additional data from a database that a user has saved against an email address.  This is all working great.

Next I want to store a copy of the email server side, as a file on disk, .msg preferred but I'll take a .eml if thats the only option.

I have 2 options but don't know if either are possible.  Either the addin generates the .msg file and posts it to the server API OR the server side API generates the .msg file directly. I have got the server side using the Outlook v2 API and able to pull back the email information when the client passes it the token, id etc.  If it could just generate/download a .msg file server side this would be ideal.

As a side note, many of the Microsoft API pages point out the deprecation of the Outlook API in favor of the Graph API, however there are inconsistent links between the pages and it get confusing.  I have discovered the token from getCallbackTokenAsync only works with the Outlook API and not Graph, but I cant find out a way to generate a graph compatible token.  All the example code from MS uses Office.context.mailbox.restUrl which still gives the Outlook API url and not Graph!

So I guess I'm trying to find out if it's even possible to get/generate a .msg or .eml file either client side using outlook.js or server side using one of the api's.  Thank you.

I can get message data both client and server side but cannot get a physical email file.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for saving messages as msg files (or getting streams). The best what you could do is to use Graph API where you could get the EML file, see [Get MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) for more information.

The server-side code may use the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) to request a new access token with permissions to Microsoft Graph. Read more about that in the [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) article.

The on-behalf-of (OBO) flow describes the scenario of a web API using an identity other than its own to call another web API. Referred to as delegation in OAuth, the intent is to pass a user's identity and permissions through the request chain.

For the middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token from the Microsoft identity platform. It only uses delegated scopes and not application roles. Roles remain attached to the principal (the user) and never to the application operating on the user's behalf. This occurs to prevent the user gaining permission to resources they shouldn't have access to. See [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's answer is good. If ultimately you need to get that message to your backend service, using Graph as Eugune described would be the recommended approach. If for whatever reason you are still looking for a capability to access it on client using Office.js, it is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process. Note there is already a couple of similar ideas there, if you search for "eml" keyword, that you may want to upvote.